# Trying to figure out how to use an extension board with Pi

Tags: arduino-motor-shield, raspberrypi

I am trying to make the following board work with Raspberry Pi.
Board Name: `L293D Motor Drive Shield Expansion Board for Arduino Mega Raspberry Pi`

[image: L293D Motor Drive Shield Expansion Board for Arduino Mega Raspberry Pi]

All I need to know is which pins do the following:

1. Enable the motor
2. Disable the motor
3. Rotate forward
4. Rotate backward

More information about the board:

1. https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/using-dc-motors
2. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=16118

Can someone please help me find this information?

Comment: Does the schematic not show this?

Comment: This is **not an Arduino question** and should be closed - it never belonged here in the first place, and it's sat abandoned by the asker for half a year now.  If it remains open, the anti-community daemon will continue to useless churn it back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following pins are in use only if the DC/Stepper noted is in use:
>
> - Digital pin 11: DC Motor #1 / Stepper #1 (activation/speed control)
> - Digital pin 3: DC Motor #2 / Stepper #1 (activation/speed control)
> - Digital pin 5: DC Motor #3 / Stepper #2 (activation/speed control)
> - Digital pin 6: DC Motor #4 / Stepper #2 (activation/speed control)
>
> The following pins are in use if any DC/steppers are used
>
> - Digital pin 4, 7, 8 and 12 are used to drive the DC/Stepper motors via the 74HC595 serial-to-parallel latch
>
> The following pins are used only if that particular servo is in use:
>
> - Digitals pin 9: Servo #1 control
> - Digital pin 10: Servo #2 control

([source](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/faq))